# Limit number of displayed items in WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, observablecollection

So I have a `ListView` control backed by an `ObservableCollection<>` which periodically gets items added to it. However I would only like to display at most the first 10 items; i.e. if there are at most 10 items it displays them all, while resizing accordingly, and if there are more than 10 it stops displaying them at the 10th item.

I was wondering if there was a reasonable way to do this as my current intuition is to have a second collection which mirrors the top 10 items of the ItemsSource, updating accordingly.

Comment: Instead of a second collection,what about filtering your collection to show just the first 10 items?

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd go about doing that. I need to maintain the underlying collection, so I'm afraid I don't know what to bind the `ListView`'s ItemsSource to, or how to filter the ItemsSource it has.

Comment: [@Pikoh](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39016120/5177728)'s idea is correct, there is also good [article](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-filtering/) with filtering example.

Comment: So when using filtering, when should I initiate the filtering? I'm currently trying to implement it in the constructor but getting `NullRefernceErrorException` as I don't think the ItemsSource has yet been set due to it being bound in Xaml and not immediately populated on load.

Comment: so when is your collection being populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (i haven't tested it, but you may get the idea):

```
_defaultView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(YourCollection);
_defaultView.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription(".", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
_defaultView.Filter = o =>
{
    int index = YourCollection.OrderBy(s => s).ToList().IndexOf(o as string);
    return index >= 0 && index < 10;
};
_defaultView.Refresh();
```

Comment: i think that should go where you collection changes (you say periodically gets items added, so i think you should do this after that happens)

Comment: Probably only `Refresh()` statement should be inside collection change handler, while all view's initialization (and also `Refresh`) should be placed in constructor after `InitializeComponent()` instruction.

Comment: Okay so I have got this mostly working, but a new issue arises. The filtering is done on each object as each object is added, however what I need it to do is to completely refresh the filtering of the whole collection each time

Comment: I sorted it by using the above after setting up a handler for `ListView.ItemSourceProperty` and then adding a handler to my `ObservableCollection<>.CollectionChanged` event to keep it updated.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using a converter for this rather than adding new model value or other extra collections as that often interferes with the change tracking.

The following filter sets the list to a fixed size of 10:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Configuration.RecentDocuments,Converter={StaticResource ItemSourceCountFilterConverter},ConverterParameter=10}"
```

This converter basically takes the original IEnumerable and filters it down to the desired count of items and returns it:

```
public  class ItemSourceCountFilterConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = value as IEnumerable;
        if (val == null)
            return value;

        int take = 10;
        if (parameter != null)
            int.TryParse(parameter as string, out take);


        if (take < 1)
            return value;
        var list = new List<object>();

        int count = 0;
        foreach (var li in val)
        {
            count++;
            if(count > take)
                break;
            list.Add(li);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```